# "A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received", What does that mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm working on a React application and I use some npm modules, one of which I had to build myself. (my NPM package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/modale-react-rm).

It is a simple modal that opens and closes with a `useState()`.

After importing my package, I have an error in my console that appears suddenly after a few seconds without performing any actions.

```
Uncaught (in promise)                                                                  localhost/:1

    >{message: 'A listener indicated an asynchronous response by r…age channel closed before a response was received'}
         message: "A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received"
        >[[Prototype]]: Object
             >constructor: ƒ ()
             >[[Prototype]]: Object

       /* sometimes there are specific elements in addition but I could not check when they appear and when not */

            Promise.then (asynchrone)       
            (anonyme)              @content_script_bundle.js:108
            handleNewFeatures      @content_script_bundle.js:101
            handleUpdatedNodes     @content_script_bundle.js:101
            (anonyme)              @content_script_bundle.js:101
            childlist(asynchrone)
            0                      @purplebox.js:1
            (anonyme)              @purplebox.js:1
            v                      @purplebox.js:1
```

[image: Error in the console img]

It doesn't block my pages, nor does it prevent the proper functioning of its features, but it's an error and I think it should be fixed and maybe help other people who have the same problem.

*I specify that I do not make any async request in this project. Everything is local and the few data I use are directly imported in raw.
I don't know where **Purplebox.js** comes from as well.*

Comment: I got the same message, and I'm not using react, just HTML/CSS/JavaScript. I'm also writing ordinary code, not Web extension code. I have no background script.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

This issue is a cross-origin request issue and it is caused by various Chrome Extensions.
I had this too in my Angular app and after testing it in the incognito mode, the error didn't show up anymore.

More info: [Google Forum](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2047906/unchecked-runtime-lasterror-the-message-port-closed-before-a-response-was-received?hl=en)

/Edit:
If you are an extension developer coming here: You need to move your cross-origin fetch request from the content script to your extensions' background page and call it from your content script. Cross-origin fetches in your content script are not allowed anymore. Don't forget the `return true` at the end of your request. More info and an example: [Chromium Project](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches/)

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed, the message is no longer present when going through private browsing. But I still don't understand why it suddenly happened...

Comment: That's hard to tell, I don't know which extensions you are using. 
Example: For me it's Ghostery, they produce many console errors. Even on their own website, I am getting these errors.

Comment: For me was an extension as well. I kept looking at my app trying to figure out where I had messed up where all it was its an extension (Ghostery).

Comment: You were right !
I'm going to remove this bloody extension (Ghostery). Thank you !!

Comment: This error doesn't appear in private browsing because the extension which is causing the error won't have access to work in private browsing.

Comment: You can add site to whitelist in Ghostery

Comment: Yes, thnx Ghosterry

Comment: The errors started popping up for me since Google Chrome update 102 or 103.

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru, did you find a solution. I have it too on my pages.

Comment: I did not. I've started living with and I continue to get annoyed by this avalanche of errors, and I just hope that Ghostery soon adjusts this with an update of their own.

Comment: Issue thread for this issue for Ghostery: https://github.com/ghostery/ghostery-extension/issues/806 Issue thread for the issue on the underlying library: https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill/issues/384

Comment: There is an open PR in the webextension-polyfill library. Applying that fixes the warning in Ghostery (for more details, see my updated answer). As far as I can tell, if the webextension-polyfill fix gets merged and released, it will take care of the project for all extension that use the library internally.

Comment: I was using React with vite, and in my case it was an extension "Reactime". just try in incognito and start looking for wich from your extension is causing the problem.

Comment: thanks for sharing your opinion, I was thinking about a memory leak.

Comment: I also had similar issue. So I removed all chrome extensions then it works for me...

Comment: It was Adobe extension for me

Comment: An extension developer here, can confirm that when I enable Firebase in the extension's content script, the error shows up and when I disable Firebase then the error goes away and the message goes through as expected.

Comment: It doesn't have to be content script -- you can get this error when fetching from options page as well, e.g. https://i.imgur.com/mrA6Zrr.png

Answer (score 74):

In my case, it is caused by [Ghostery extension](https://www.ghostery.com/), if this error appears in your local host, you need to add it to the trusted sites list of Ghostery and the error will be gone.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I believe, it is always a good idea to whitelist localhost in all browser extensions to prevent them intercepting with local development.

Comment: clicking "Trust Site" did not work for me, I had to go into the three dots menu, Trust & Restrict, and add "127.0.0.1:*" to the trust list. After that, the error is gone! thank you

Comment: I do not use Ghostery, but got this message.

Answer (score 15):

The background script (service worker in MV3) could be going to inactive state without sending a response back to a message it received from a content script.

Example:

**Background script:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  // ... handle message
  return true // Error message says you already return true
})
```

Most MV3 APIs are asynchronous and can return promises when it makes sense to do so. (In some cases, like event listeners (e.g.: chrome.tabs.onRemoved), returning a promise wouldn't make sense).  Reading a response back however can be done using callbacks or promise-style.

**Content script: method 1 to read response:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('ping', (response) => { /* read response */ })
```

**Content script: method 2 to read response:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('ping').then(response => { /* read response */ })
```

The issue you are facing is this:  background script does not invoke `sendResponse()` for one/more messages it received and went inactive (causing the message channel to close).  However, the content script that sent the message is waiting for the response.

Please check your message senders & handlers.

Answer (score 10):

It has been [discussed in the `webextension-polyfill` library](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill/issues/384), which is used by many extensions (including Ghostery). There was a [recent change in Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/9256bc8b668f61e755ab587f623e7da94d8a6f47%5E!/#F4) that introduced to the error message.

For projects that are using the polyfill, I would expect the warning to go away if a fix is merged. Note that the polyfill library is used, since only Firefox implements the new promised-based [runtime.onMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage), while Chrome still enforces the [original callback-style API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onMessage).

Note that there is an [open pull request](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill/pull/385) in the webextension-polyfill library already. It has not been merged, but according to my tests, it solves the problem. So, if you need a quick fix for a project that uses the library internally, you can manually apply the patch with [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package). For instance, [this is how such a change would look like in Ghostery](https://github.com/ghostery/ghostery-extension/pull/830).

Comment: so it looks like this is not an issue that needs to be considered. The [Pull Request](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill/pull/385/files) mentioned above  is just to ignore the error when its encountered

Comment: @Gangula It depends on the context whether you can ignore the warning. In many case where extension are using the webextension-polyfill, it is safe to ignore it IMHO, since that used to the semantic. In general, the warning means that a promise is created in a listener that will neither be resolved or rejected. That may indicate a logical error in the code, but there exists older code that has been written in that style. For new code, I would avoid this communication pattern - I see the point why Chrome warns - but it may not be straightforward to change in a larger code base.

Comment: makes sense. I'm working on a extension where i'm facing this error, but i'm pretty sure that my logic is correct and the expected functionality is working as expected too. I'm doing some more tests, will add more details if I find any

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error. I removed the **Tampermonkey** extension and tweaked my **AdBlock** extension and then it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This error normally occurs due to using of different Chrome extension. It can be removed by removing the AD Blocker.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue couple of days ago, and found out that the error is caused by the runtime Message Handler. to solve it, just add a callback function as 3rd parameter to chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener.

forgot how i found the solution, but it works for me.

```js
// to avoid the error, the parameter [sendResponse] is necessary!
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  // do something ...

  // this line seems meaningless but you have to invoke it to avoid error.
  sendResponse({damn: true});
});
```

Comment: My listeners are ordinary and not part of runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to ad blockers or similar. Just exclude the site for this application.
In my case it was AdBlock app. It kept showing this error in the console when working with LiveServer or FiveServer. It does not affect anything, but it is very annoying

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on my react app when i introduced an infinite loop through useEffect, the thing is that you most likely won't see too much change in your app or problem. For me it even helped reload some state for functions that i was still to write but over time it will introduce bugs and performance issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Avast Online Security & Privacy 22.11.173 is causing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Windows 11 machine.
I added these lines at the bottom of the hosts file in the `drivers/etc` directory:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error couple of days ago and it showed up in my console, when i was testing/debugging a jquery function in dev tools. Although It didn't block page, nor this error prevented the functioning of any features.

For me it was happening only when working on secure .aspx pages on localhost and my Login Session expires (as error doesn't happen in public pages or simple html pages) and on Re-login the error disappears. It may be bacuase of cross-origin fetch request from other scripts extesion, as sugested by Chrostip Schaejn

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in a Databricks SQL warehouse connection use-case.

```
connection = sql.connect(
                 server_hostname = hostname_var,
                 http_path = http_path_of_sql_wh,
                 access_token = access_token
                )
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

I was using the package `from databricks import sql`

Reference pypi package: [databricks-sql-connector](https://pypi.org/project/databricks-sql-connector/)

I didn't close the connection so I was getting

> "A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but
> the message channel closed before a response was received"

Answer (score 0):

Anyone coming here while searching for the error message while working on extension development. The issue in case was not related to cross-origin fetch since my extension is not any fetch at all... The issue was that my onMessage listener were returning true instead of false. The documentation says to return a boolean or a promise but does not clearly indicate when the boolean should be true or false... :-(