# "Unhandled error" appears in the console while the error is well handled

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, unhandled

I started to learn how to use the Vue.js framework a little while ago, and I got stuck with this situation.

I use the jQuery.ajax() method to make requests to a web api. For each of these ajax requests (I'll use the login request as an example), in case of error, I redirect the code to a function called callbackError like this:

```
async login() {
    await $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: `${this.$ROOT_API}/Users/login/${this.username}/${this.password}`,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: this.loginSuccessCallback,
        error: this.callbackError
    });
}
```

The callbackError() function simply displays an error popup.

```
callbackError(request, status, error) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Error',
        icon: 'error',
        text: `${request} ${status} ${error}`,
        confirmButtonText: '<i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>',
        background: this.$COLORS.navbar,
        color: this.$COLORS.font,
        confirmButtonColor: this.$COLORS.primary
    })
}
```

Now, if I cause an error during the connection by entering a wrong password, the popup is displayed correctly (I know it's not very telling, I'll fix it later).

[image: error popup]

But despite the fact that the popup was displayed, which proves that the error was handled, I still have these error messages in the console that tell me that there was an unhandled error:

[image: error messages in the console]

Honestly I don't even know what to try to fix the problem I just feel like my browser is blatantly lying to me that I didn't handle the error.

**PS :** I don't have the Ghostery extension so I don't think it's the same problem as on this question:
["A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received", What does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72494154/a-listener-indicated-an-asynchronous-response-by-returning-true-but-the-messag)

**UPDATE :**

I now use the axios library to make my requests to the web api, and it works fine.

```
async loginAsync() {
    await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `api/Users/login/${this.username}/${this.password}`
    })
    .then(response => this.loginSuccessCallback(response))
    .catch(error => this.$CALLBACK_ERROR(error))
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [.fail()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) method in jQuery?

Comment: Do you happen to be using an extension called Ghostery? [similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72494154/a-listener-indicated-an-asynchronous-response-by-returning-true-but-the-messag)

Comment: @yoduh I don't have this extension. Do you think that the problem is not actually in my code?

Comment: @HuyPhạm Doesn't the 'error' property of $.ajax() already have the same use?

Comment: @CeFameuxTom It's deprecated if I remember correctly

Comment: @HuyPhạm Well, you were certainly right, I think that's where the mistake came from, because I now use axios and it works well